# ListView with drawable images is laggy

Tags: java, android, android-listview

**SOLUTION FOUND (THANKYOU FOR ANSWERS!)
IT WAS THE HIGH FILE SIZE OF DRAWABLES (.PNG)**

I have a listview and many .png images in my /drawables folder. As I load these images in my imageview of the listview item the scrolling of the listview gets laggy

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.store_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.store_image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(stores[position]);
        switch(position){
                case 0: Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.first).into(holder.store_image);break;
                ///... more cases ...
                default: break;
                }
            }

        return convertView;

    }
```

I am implementing this in the NavigationDrawer

**EDIT:**

I also tried this method of creating and drawable array and then setting the imageview but still its laggy.

```
//in the adapter
int[] store_images = new int[]{R.drawable.first,...and so on}; 
// and then in getView()
holder.store_image.setImageResource(store_images[position]);
```

Comment: Funny as both of those properties would make it worse :)

Comment: Can you explain what is being done in this method
Picasso.with(context).load()

Comment: @user3249477 I removed those two properties still its laaggy.

Comment: @AjitPratapSingh picasso is a library to load images. search on github

Comment: The file size of one drawable is 19KB.

Comment: Try loading all images in an array of drawables during adapter initialization. Then reference them from that array by position id rather than running switch() and load every time

Comment: @AlexanderZhak I implemented your technique. check edit in OP

Comment: Turn on hardware acceleration

Answer (score 0):

Edited Code

Try this Code!!

```
           ArrayList<Boolean> alDone= new   ArrayList<Boolean>();

                public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                final ViewHolder holder;
                                if (convertView == null) {
                                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
                                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                                    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                                    holder.store_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.store_image);
                                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                                }
                                else{
                                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                                }

                                holder.title.setText(stores[position]);

                               if(position==0){

                                if(!alDone.get(position)){
    Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.first).into(holder.store_image);
alDone.add(true,position)
        }
                    }
                                return convertView;

                            }
```

Comment: I removed the thread! I am using switch case instead of if() because i have multiple images to show. but still its laggy

Comment: Don't load picasso every time. once image is loaded for that position dont' load it again. I have edited code. I hope it helps.

Comment: I get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 (at the if(!aldone) statement)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using your inflater is incorrect.

Try this:

```
 convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
```

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

This may help the lag. Picasso is very good framework and will cache images for you, so it is probably not the cause.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Okay! So the problem was the 19kb file size! I decreased the file size to 5-6kb and the lag is gone! although if you have the same problem as mine answers of others can be of help too!

Answer (score 0):

There can be many causes of laggy list views:

1. Your xml layout: Do you use RelativeLayout or nested layout? Then layouting while scrolling may be the problem. Solution: flat layouts
2. To me it seems like you try to implement different view types. So split your layout xml file in two and define two view types. One for the first element in the list and one for the others.
3. Do you load lot of images? then the Garbage Collection may be the problem because it will block the UI thread until GC has finished. Check the logcat. Here you will find how many times GC runs and how much time it takes. As I have seen you use Picasso. There is a feature which is not part of picasso yet (still a pull request) that handles this problem by adding a OnScrollListener to the ListView / RecyclerView: https://github.com/square/picasso/pull/561

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Picasso if you aren't loading images from the web. Your code:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.first).into(holder.store_image);
```

suggests you already have your images stored within your app, so just load them directly into your ImageView.

On another note, from the docs on [ImageView#setImageResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)):

> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can
>   cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using
>   setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or
>   setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.